# How to view and change data of a .mdf file using MS Access?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

**Background:** I have an .mdf database containing some numeric values that I need to change (specifically, scale and offset values for sensors). The database was created by a Visual Basic program that controls some lab equipment and stores pertinent data in the .mdf file. Please excuse my rudimentary knowledge of the topic; I'm a *complete* novice when it comes to SQL Server and VB.

After searching through many posts, I understand that to open the .mdf file, you must "attach" it in Microsoft Server Management Studio (I'm using that with SQL Server 2005), which I have successfully done.

**Problem:** It seems that this only allows me to view and modify the structure of the database, ie. tables, columns, data types etc., rather than the values of the database itself.

Is there a way to do this manually, like how you can edit the field data of .mdb files in MS Access?  Again, sorry for my limited knowledge on the topic. I'll gladly provide extra details where needed.

Comment: The Microsoft Server Management Studio should also allow you to open an individual table, usually with the 1000 records to look at or with the first 200 records to edit. Try and do a right mouse click on the table you see in the object explorer on the left.

Comment: @cars10 why use the klunky UI for this? The edit data UI places a bunch of unnecessary locks and has other limitations and even bugs. It's not a spreadsheet.

Comment: You can use the `UPDATE` command in a query window to modify data. [Lots of examples in the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I was not seriously suggesting she did all the changes in the UI - it was just a first stept to show that data access *is* actually possiblt using SSMS. Of course, when it comes to shifting values in a large number there is nothing better than an `UPDATE` statement in a query window. But it can be a bit daunting for a newbie coming to grips with the syntax at first.

Answer (score 1):

You mention you want to use access. That can be done. Your database is up and running after attaching it.

In Access you can simply create an ODBC connection in access and use Access to edit/modify your data as much as you want. you can also create queries.

It is in the menu item "external data" [I'm guessing because I use a dutch version]. You select to create a "linked table", choose your server and you are done.

Comment: I am not a complete novice when it comes to SQL Server and VS and I had problems figuring out how to access a mdf file from Access. The YouTube video in [import SQL Server DB tables into Access 2010 - Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_other/import-sql-server-db-tables-into-access-2010/94d00d07-e130-4c75-89da-6941b6075ef8?auth=1) helped enough that I finally figure it out. Someone should write a text description as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the table you want to modify in SSMS and select "Edit Top 200 Rows".

If you have more than 200 rows to edit, you can connect to the SQL Server database with either Access or Excel.

Here are the instructions for Access:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/connect-an-access-project-to-a-microsoft-sql-server-database-adp-HP005274586.aspx

Comment: Sorry, the page you mentioned can’t be found.