# How do I access a 3rd party database using Access

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a scheduling software that has a database of clients, client pets, pets grooming styles, appointments and invoices.
The generic reports that are given with the software are not giving me the information that I need to go. Support from the software company is telling me to use Access to build the reports that I require.
I am not seeing how to connect to the software's DB to use in Access to generate my custom reports.
Any help or links to the information for this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance everybody

Comment: What platform is the software? Another Access file? You have to find the folder location where the file resides. If it is an Access file, should be simple to set table links with the External Data utility. If it is a split design, the tables will be in a separate file from the user interface but possibly in the same folder location. The company should be able to give you info on the db structure and file names to look for.

Comment: I'm running on Windows. The db is a .mdf extension.

Comment: The company's support is like going to the dentist, its pulling teeth just to get the info they came me, likes months of bitching to get just what I posted in my question.

Comment: I Googled "Access .mdf" and got this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340251/how-to-view-and-change-data-of-a-mdf-file-using-ms-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of MS Access' unique features is connecting to external RDBMs' ( SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, MySQL, SQLite) in complement to its default Jet/ACE SQL Engine. In fact, Access can connect to any other ODBC-compliant system even Quickbooks or your software assuming it has an ODBC API.

An .MDF is a SQL Server main database file but usually you do not connect directly to the file but the server instance. Most likely, you are required to connect Access to the SQL Server database the software sits on. In fact, you will be doing what the software does: connect to a backend database. No software or web/mobile app is without a database or data store of some kind.

MS Access backend setup is very easy with many online tutorials:

1. Find the SQL Server instance and all needed credentials (server address or host, port, schema, user, password).
2. Be sure to have an installed ODBC Driver (usually already available if SQL Server is installed) or check if software has a pre-defined DSN. Free MSSQL ODBC downloads are available online. Open `odbcad32.exe` to see current computer driver/DSN installs.
3. In a saved Access .accdb/.mdb database, under *External Data* tab in MSAccess.exe, click ODBC database (globe icon) where you walk through a wizard to connect to aforementioned Driver or DSN (machine or user). You can either import tables or link live tables which upon successful connection will prompt you to select the database tables.

From there you can use linked tables like any other local table within MS Access including forms, reports, macros, and modules.

In fact, knowing the ODBC connection you can work in most programming languages that maintain database APIs including Python, PHP, R, Perl, Java, C#, VB, even your everyday MS Excel to interact with scheduling software's data.

Comment: Haha! Glad to help.